# Web preview from backend VS ordinary link

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html, backend

I have this problem that my website is good looking when I preview it from Wordpress backend and has no errors. You can check it here - [Clean version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbp64.jpg) However when I preview it by simply typing my website address into the bar, it is a little mess. Kindly check it here - [Crappy version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlhAy.jpg)

I tried clearing the cache, updating the browser, tried few different browsers but no luck. One another weird thing is that on my colleage's computer the website shows perfectly.

Comment: When you inspect your network activity, do any requests fail? Specifically on the CSS section. Also, there is a Stack Exchange network for wordpress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer and interests. I am very new to wordpress and programming world, so I do not understand what exactly you meant by inspecting network activity. 

May you please explain in detail?